# Ranking and obtaining data across moving window

Tags: google-bigquery, window-functions, rank

I have following table -

```
create table iphone_defects(
    product string
    ,defect string
    ,qty int64
    ,fwkyr int64
    ,fwenddate date
);

insert into iphone_defects values ('iPhone','Glass breakage',100,202112,'2020-09-20');
insert into iphone_defects values ('iPhone','No sound',30,202111,'2020-09-30');
insert into iphone_defects values ('iPhone','Glass breakage',25,202110,'2020-09-06');
insert into iphone_defects values ('iPhone','Audio problem',20,202109,'2020-08-30');
insert into iphone_defects values ('iPhone','No sound',60,202108,'2020-08-23');
insert into iphone_defects values ('iPhone','Empty boxes',30,202107,'2020-08-16');
insert into iphone_defects values ('iPhone','Audio problem',25,202106,'2020-08-09');
```

Am expecting the following result -

[image]

fwkyr refers to Financial Week in a year. I have added in additional column fwenddate basically referring to max date in the financial week of the year.

Basically the ask is to obtain the defect with largest quantity in a 4 week window from the current week. Say for the fwkyr - 202112, the highest defects is for 'Glass breakage' and the total quantity is 100.

This is a static window. My actual use case needs 52 week.

Without the moving window, I know that I can rank and get the data but not sure on how to even approach this problem. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Per updated question my updated solution gets much longer and changes quite a bit.

I am still not sure if user selects from which week you need another 52 weeks or if you are looking at this calculation from start (week 1) of every year.

I also assume that you have a typo in one of your insert statements when I compare to your desired output table. So I changed it to fit your output table.

---

**1. Create table**

```
create table table.defects(
    product string
    ,defect string
    ,qty int64
    ,fwkyr int64
    ,fwenddate date
);
```

---

**2. Insert data** (adjusted last insert to match your output table)

```
insert into table.defects values ('iPhone','Glass breakage',100,202112,'2020-09-20');
insert into table.defects values ('iPhone','No sound',30,202111,'2020-09-30');
insert into table.defects values ('iPhone','Glass breakage',25,202110,'2020-09-06');
insert into table.defects values ('iPhone','Audio problem',20,202109,'2020-08-30');
insert into table.defects values ('iPhone','No sound',60,202108,'2020-08-23');
insert into table.defects values ('iPhone','Empty boxes',30,202107,'2020-08-16');
insert into table.defects values ('iPhone','Audio problem',55,202106,'2020-08-09');
```

---

**3. Query for results**

```
###############################################################################
### start count of weeks since selected first week and
### get number of weeks by desired range
###############################################################################


WITH
  get_weeks AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY product ORDER BY fwkyr DESC) AS week_numbering,
    SPLIT(CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY product ORDER BY fwkyr)/4 AS string), '.')[
  OFFSET
    (0)] AS week_id_0,
  FROM
    table.defects 
  ORDER BY
  fwkyr DESC
),

###############################################################################
### produce filter column for each window period by offsetting 
###############################################################################

  get_weeks_consequtive AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    LAG(week_id_0,1) OVER(PARTITION BY product ORDER BY fwkyr DESC) AS week_id_1,
    LAG(week_id_0,2) OVER(PARTITION BY product ORDER BY fwkyr DESC) AS week_id_2,
    LAG(week_id_0,3) OVER(PARTITION BY product ORDER BY fwkyr DESC) AS week_id_3
  FROM
    get_weeks ),
    

###############################################################################
### create tables and calculations per window using filter column where you group by for qty and keep top qty only
###############################################################################
    
  week_id_0 AS (
  SELECT
    SUM(qty) AS qty,
    product,
    defect,
    week_id
  FROM (
    SELECT
      * EXCEPT(week_id_0,
        week_id_1,
        week_id_2,
        week_id_3),
      MAX(fwkyr) OVER() AS week_id
    FROM
      get_weeks_consequtive
    WHERE
      week_id_0 = '1' )
  GROUP BY
    2,
    3,
    4
  ORDER BY
    1 DESC
  LIMIT
    1),
    


  week_id_1 AS (
  SELECT
    SUM(qty) AS qty,
    product,
    defect,
    week_id
  FROM (
    SELECT
      * EXCEPT(week_id_0,
        week_id_1,
        week_id_2,
        week_id_3),
      MAX(fwkyr) OVER() AS week_id
    FROM
      get_weeks_consequtive
    WHERE
      week_id_1 = '1' )
  GROUP BY
    2,
    3,
    4
  ORDER BY
    1 DESC
  LIMIT
    1),



  week_id_2 AS (
  SELECT
    SUM(qty) AS qty,
    product,
    defect,
    week_id
  FROM (
    SELECT
      * EXCEPT(week_id_0,
        week_id_1,
        week_id_2,
        week_id_3),
      MAX(fwkyr) OVER() AS week_id
    FROM
      get_weeks_consequtive
    WHERE
      week_id_2 = '1' )
  GROUP BY
    2,
    3,
    4
  ORDER BY
    1 DESC
  LIMIT
    1),


  week_id_3 AS (
  SELECT
    SUM(qty) AS qty,
    product,
    defect,
    week_id
  FROM (
    SELECT
      * EXCEPT(week_id_0,
        week_id_1,
        week_id_2,
        week_id_3),
      MAX(fwkyr) OVER() AS week_id
    FROM
      get_weeks_consequtive
    WHERE
      week_id_3 = '1' )
  GROUP BY
    2,
    3,
    4
  ORDER BY
    1 DESC
  LIMIT
    1)



###############################################################################
### union all selected windows 
###############################################################################

  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    week_id_0


  UNION ALL


  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    week_id_1


  UNION ALL


  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    week_id_2


  UNION ALL


  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    week_id_3

ORDER BY
  week_id DESC
```

---

get_weeks

[image: get_weeks]

---

get_weeks_consequtive

[image: get_weeks_consequtive]

---

week_id_1

[image: week_id_1]

---

result

[image: result]

---

**PS** ---
I brainstormed this quick per your update perhaps there is a better way and I would be interested in seeing it.

Anyhow, with such lengthy queries I typically produce a python script with text templates for repetitive parts and use a loop to expand repetitive parts to desired lengths by incrementing changing values and inserting them with so called f strings.

Comment: Thanks @Yev Guyduy. I have added in additional detail to help. fwkyr refers to week of a financial year. Your query is not giving the expected result but at least it's given me idea of how to approach the problem. Am working on it now.

Comment: @VKarthik fyi I updated my answer according to your updated question